# Send a email through googleapi gmail python using oauth2

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to send a email as a user using OAuth 2. On Google's website [they state](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism):

> This document defines the SASL XOAUTH2 mechanism for use with the IMAP AUTHENTICATE and SMTP AUTH commands. This mechanism allows the use of OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens to authenticate to a user's Gmail account.

Using the tests provided in their `oauth2.py`

```
smtp_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_conn.set_debuglevel(True)
smtp_conn.ehlo('test')
smtp_conn.starttls()
smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string))
```

where you can test whether or not you can connect to their smtp servers using a provided access token it succeeds, but when I try to send a email using `sendmail` I get a failure.

If I add `smtp_conn.sendmail('from@test.com', 'to@test.com', 'msg')` it says that I need to authenticate.

From the docs am I not authenticating when I send the `AUTH` command with the required auth string?

Thanks.

UPDATE ***

So apparently if I re authenticate in the catch of a try catch statement it works.. Any ideas?

```
try:
    smtp_conn.sendmail('fromt@test.com', 'to@test.com', 'cool')
except:
    smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string))
    smtp_conn.sendmail('from@test.com', 'to@test.com', 'cool')
```

Comment: You should be using to@example.com. to@test.com may be a real email address, in which case you may be spamming them.

Comment: those are just sample emails to show how the code works.... when I actually run the code I use my own emails

Answer (score 1):

You need another ehlo call after starttls. So:

```
    smtp_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp_conn.set_debuglevel(True)
    smtp_conn.ehlo()
    smtp_conn.starttls()
    smtp_conn.ehlo()
    smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string))
```

Comment: how come you have to do that twice? and if so how does that try catch work?